# encrypted /home won't decrypt after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, encrypted-partition

I did a clean install of beta 2 10.11 and pointed the install to my /home which is on a separate partition. I also checked encrypt home. Once installed, my documents folder is "empty" but there is still 100gb of space being used. If I use sudo ecryptfs-recover-private it will mount the old /home to a /tmp folder and I can see the contents. How do I fix this so that my /home decrypts normally when I log in? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would just try copying the relevant data from your old /home partition across. There are probably other ways, but this is likely the easiest. Good luck.